# Children's sci-fi collection - Alien orthodontist

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

When I was a child in the 70s I would stay with my grand parents and read children's sci fi.  They had a particular book containing a collection of short stories one of which was about a human guy whose job was to fly around space cleaning the teeth of giant space creatures.  He was so small in comparison to the giant aliens teeth that he was no bigger than their smallest teeth.

Can anyone let me know if they know the story, author or the collection of stories?

I would love to find this book again.

Comment: Hi, the dentist was human, not alien.  The reason I used orthodontist was a vague (possibly/probably incorrect) recollection that the word was used in the title of the short story.  Thanks tho, I didn't know the difference 

Comment: @FuzzyBoots OP was looking for a COLLECTION of scifi stories ONE of which was about a space dentist. I suggested *Young Extraterrestrilals* (a bit later that the 70s when the OP says he read it); the OP's comment acknowledges that the space dentist was Anthon's Dr. Dillingham but I don't see where he accepts *Young Extraterrestrials* as the book. (*Prostho Plus* is out as its ALL about the space dentist.) Not a dupe because (a) unaccepted and (b) *Young Extraterrestrials* != "Monarch". Your thoughts?

Comment: @user14111: It's Complicated. The querent asked for the collection, story, or author, and it seems that they didn't think it was *Young Extraterrestrials*. And, based on the description, it now seems unlikely they were thinking of Monarch. I probably acted too quickly.

Answer (score 18):

[Piers Anthony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piers_Anthony)'s novel [*Prostho Plus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostho_Plus) is a fix-up of his series of short stories about a [prosthodontist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthodontics) named [Dr. Dillingham](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?24298) who is abducted by aliens and forced to travel around the universe fixing the teeth of various alien monsters.

One of those short stories, ["In the Jaws of Danger"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54232), appeared in an anthology called [*Young Extraterrestrials*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?276716) which featured a picture of Dr. Dillingham on [the cover](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/c/c8/YNGXTRTRRS1984.jpg), working on a giant tooth, but that came out in 1984, too late to be the book you're thinking of.

You can read some of the Dr. Dillingham stories for free at the Internet Archive:

["In the Jaws of Danger", *If*, November 1967.](https://archive.org/stream/1967-11_IF#page/n107/mode/1up)

["Getting Through University", *If*, August 1968.](https://archive.org/stream/1968-08_IF#page/n7/mode/1up)

["None but I", *If*, October 1969.](https://archive.org/stream/1969-10_IF#page/n29/mode/1up)

["Monarch", *If*, November-December, 1970.](https://archive.org/stream/1970-11-12_IF#page/n125/mode/1up)

The fix-up novel [*Prostho Plus*](https://archive.org/details/prosthoplus00anth) can be "borrowed" from the Internet Archive (registration required).

Comment: The story was indeed prostho plus! Thank you for your help.  I'm just looking for the collection of short stories this was a part of now.  A collection of sci fi shorts for kids that is, not a collection of dental scifi.

Comment: @owenwright: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2324166.Extraterrestrials was where I encountered it first.

Comment: In isfdb, under  "Series: Dr. Dillingham" they mention 
Prostho Plus **(1967)**;  In the Jaws of Danger (1967); Getting Through University (1968);  None But I (1969); Monarch (1970); Prostho Plus (1971) ; Ouch! (1974)
Now I understand that Prostho Plus (1971)  is a fix-up of the previous short stories. Not quite clear to me what Prostho Plus (1967) is, since at best only "Jaws of Danger" was published before. Moreover about "Ouch" they mention it is taken from the beginning of Prostho Plus. Now in "Jaws" there is a very loud "Ouch", by the prince whale, so that could make sense.

Comment: @user14111 However there is no story mentioned between *In the Jaws of Danger* and *Getting Through University*, but in the timeline of ths stories it is clear that Dr. Dillingham visited a planet called Electrolus between these two stories. So were the event there **never** published in detail (but just very rapidly sketched in *Getting Through University*), or did Piers Anthony write a more detailed version in his 1971 fix-up novel ? Thanks !

Comment: @user14111 One more question. I just wonder whether I finished reading "None but I" on the Internet Archive. Page 52 of "Worlds of IF" ends on the line, by the Jann : "And I could not tell thee," and followed by the remark (Please turn to page 100) but page 100 is in the middle of the story "The Seeds of Gonyl". I haven't found the end of the Jann's sentence, cut off after a comma. Any idea of where to find this end ? The story is almost finished, somehow, Dr. Dillingham almost assured to live to the ripe age of 94, unless he dies of sickness or accident before. Still a bit unsatisfactory.

Comment: @Alfred Typo, for p. 100 read p. 160.

Comment: @user14111 Ah, yes, I finally found it. The (paper) page is numbered 160, but is only 155 of the electronic document. I did look at every page till the end, but only on a small format to have 12 pages together, and I missed it. Thanks a lot !!!!! What about  the Electrolus story ? Only the extremely short allusion in *Getting through University*, or is there an extended one in the fix-up novel ? I only read the four stories you mention above, in Internet Archive. I don't know how to access the full novel.

Comment: @Alfred The novel *Prostho Plus* can be "borrowed" from the Internet Archive; it's free, but registration is required. Link: https://archive.org/details/prosthoplus00anth

Comment: @user14111 Thanks a lot ! I'll do it tomorrow (french time; it is almost midnight here, bedtime for me)

Comment: @user14111 So I now have read all the parts of Prostho Plus that are outside the four stories above that I had just read or reread. A lot of fun. I wonder if Piers Anthony already had the part on Electrolus in mind when he wrote *Getting through University*. If not, he did a fantastic job to write, for the 1971 fix-up, the part on Electrolus in coherence with what he had already written in 1968. The end is so sweet.... Thanks so much for giving me the reference !

Comment: @user14111 I gave you a bounty, since I think your answer should have been accepted. And also because your advices have been extremely helpful to me in several occasions. Following your suggestion I also gave a bounty to an answer by DavidW, completely unrelated to "Ado", but that also happened to be obviously correct but **not accepted**, about "Discworld". The other answer on "Ado" I just accepted. It is very nice to find helpful people like you. Thanks for all !